# Input data in the loss function of a deep learning model

Tags: tensorflow, input, deep-learning, loss-function

I am training an RNN using tensorflow where I am using some input data in my custom loss function.
I have attached the input data that I want to use in my custom loss to my target values so that when I shuffle it gets shuffled accordingly.So, output_tensor looks such:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(900, 2), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[4.0370e+03, 1.0000e+00],
       [9.3000e+02, 0.0000e+00],
       [2.6290e+03, 0.0000e+00],
       ...,
       [1.6980e+03, 1.0000e+00],
       [4.9200e+02, 0.0000e+00],
       [1.1202e+04, 1.0000e+00]])>
```

I have defined my loss function as:

```
def custom_loss(output_tensor, target_pred):
    target_true=output_tensor[:,0]
    data_in_loss=output_tensor[:,1]
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(data_in_loss*(target_true-target_pred)+(1-data_in_loss)*tf.abs(target_true-target_pred))
```

and my model as:

```
def create_LSTM():
    model= tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None,14), dtype=tf.float64, ragged=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10),    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu')])
    
   
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=optimizer, experimental_run_tf_function=False)
    return model

model_LSTM = create_LSTM()
history=model.fit(input_tensor, output_tensor, epochs=10, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

When I run this, model does not converge.

Comment: One of the things I noticed is that your last LSTM cell is set with return_seq=True... your model returns a 3d output while your target is 2d (this is not the reason of the error but a point to take into account)

Comment: Just fixed it,thanks. Apparently I made a mistake while copying the code. But as you said, problem still persists.

Comment: second question... do you know the difference between tf.compat.v1.losses.absolute_difference and MAE ?

Comment: why do you use input_shape=(None,14) as input_shape?what is the shape of your input_tensor?

Comment: @Marco Cerliani A little late but I don't really understand the difference when I look at the documentation In tf.compat.v1.losses.absolute_difference it says 'adds an abs. difference loss to the training procedure'. Whereas in tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError it says 'computes the mean of absolute difference btwn labels and predictions'. So is taking the mean of losses only difference?

Comment: I am using a ragged tensor and shape is (900,None,14) @Tou

Comment: I suggest u to manual try MeanAbsoluteError and absolute_difference and check if there are differences... I think it's a single number, is it what are you looking for? is it appropriate to put this in your loss?

Comment: I just edited my loss function, please check it.Now I can run my model however model does not seem to converge.I guess I could not write my loss function properly. What I am trying to achive is; if data_in_loss== 1, I need to punish the model if predicted value is smaller than the actual.If pred is bigger than actual; no punishment happens as long as data_in_loss=1. On the other hand, if data_in_loss!=1, I want to use the absolute difference in loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in some scenario in your loss function, the loss value is a negative value.
For data_in_loss == 1, if you want to punish the model when predicted value is smaller than the actual and no punishment in other case, you can use zero instead of negative values :

```
def custom_loss(output_tensor, target_pred):
target_true=output_tensor[:,0]
data_in_loss=output_tensor[:,1]
return tf.math.reduce_mean(data_in_loss*tf.where((target_true-target_pred) <0 
 ,0.,(target_true-target_pred))+(1- 
         data_in_loss)*tf.abs(target_true-target_pred))
```